# redirect after inlog facebook

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I am making a game for facebook, and i want them to be able to login and then go in the game.
I have the login button with the popup screen and permissions i need from them, but i cant get them to redirect back to my url.

i use this code :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=380841622050947";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  window.navigate("www.google.com");
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')); </script>

<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="5" data-size="xlarge" data-show-faces="true" data-auto-logout-link="false" scope="email,publish_stream"></div>
```

What am i missing?

i tried using this :

```
window.navigate(”top.jsp”);
```

But i cant seem to catch the "player logged in" action, so i can redirect after that.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I tried your code and it's working fine for me, after login I was redirected to the same page only. What's the issue?

Comment: When you get back to the page, it should be "refreshed" cause if you refresh, it will show the game, if you don't refresh, well it won't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to redirect the user after successful login, you can use [`FB.Event.subscribe`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/)-

Complete code would be-

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=380841622050947";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')); 

   window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '380841622050947',
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
      });
      FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(r){
         console.log(r.status);
         if ( r.status === 'connected'){
              window.location.href = '{redirect-to-url}'
         }
      });
    };
</script>

<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="5" data-size="xlarge" data-show-faces="true" data-auto-logout-link="false" scope="email,publish_stream"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that you're not using the complete code necessary to be able to login via JS SDK. Have a look at the guide under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web

Comment: Yeah i've looked there, but this worked quite well, the only thing it doesn't do, is show my app after login, it just stays at a white page with the faces of your friends that liked it

Comment: Yeah, because you're using the wrong/incomplete code.